# Sign in with apple verify identity token in correct way?

Tags: ios

I have a native ios app, when using sign in with apple in the app , and after the user is successfully authenticated, the apple server returns an identity token, authorization code, and user identifier to app, after that, app then send request my server with identity token and authorization code

so what i want to ask is can i verify identity token directly , or need using authorization code to send request to apple api, apple will response same identity token to my server
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens)

is it necessary to re get identity token by using authorization code? 
or just verify identity token from app client just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want better security, I would recommend sending the authorization code to Apple's server for validation, this is in case the client side has been tampered (eg: user jailbreak their phone and modified the identityToken parsing function etc).

If you are not worried on client side much (internal apps or casual apps), I think its fine to just verify identity token on client side.